# How to get CSS selectors to work in the Developer Tools for Chrome 17?

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-selectors, google-chrome-devtools

It appears that the search window of the Dev Tools in Chrome 17 no longer matches CSS selectors.  Boo.  I know I can use the JS console but it really, really helps me to see the matches within the context of the DOM.  If anyone knows how I can still achieve this or alternatively, how to revert to a previous (i.e. the one I had yesterday) version of chrome I would appreciate it.

Comment: Wow, I was never aware of such a feature. Shame they took it out of Chrome... I wonder what reason they had for doing so.

Comment: It is documented right at the bottom of [this Google Code page](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/elements.html) ...except it isn't true anymore as far as I can tell.

Comment: I was using this feature hundreds of times a day. A damn shame

Comment: The documentation for the $ and $$ CSS selectors appears to have moved to here: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console#selecting-elements

Answer (score 29, accepted):

<del>I haven't been able to find any workaround to get CSS selectors working in the search bar again.</del> [Rejoice, for they have returned!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10640999/106224)

In any case, you can still use `document.querySelectorAll()` with a selector in the JS console, then right-click on any of the matched elements and choose **Reveal in Elements Panel** and it'll show you where it is in the DOM, just as with previous versions.

Comment: You can also use `$$` as a shortcut instead of typing out all of `document.querySelectorAll`.

Comment: I have filed a bug report about this, please star it so we can get this feature working again: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=127440

Comment: Domenic, or even: `inspect($$('div.foo')[0])`

Comment: $('div.foo') in the chrome dev tools console...shows them all

Answer (score 66):

Another way is to use `$$` in the console, for example:

```
$$("#contents ul.features")
```

Comment: I have two input elements, one of which does not have a name attribute. When I search for inputs using $$, I only get the element which has name attribute. Is this the correct behavior or am I missing something ? If this is the correct behavior, then please explain why it returns one input instead of both. Thanks !

Answer (score 26):

This was an unintended regression in Chrome that we didn't catch. Luckily Ariel (in the comments here) [filed a ticket](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=127440) and it was fixed two days later.

If all goes well, it'll make its way to the stable channel in about 11 weeks. However **the feature is now available in Chrome Canary**, so I recommend using that.

[image]

Comment: Great to see it back! And I would upvote again for capturing your answer in your screenshot.

Comment: Hurray!  Just makes life a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

I verify Css and XPath selectors using [Natu WebSync extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/natu-websync/aohpgnblncapofbobbilnlfliihianac).

It can:

- split selector to parts and verify them separately
- show with color how many elements are found for each selector part. 0 - Red, 1 - Green, several - Yellow
- highlight elements on the page when I hover selector part
- navigate to selector element in Elements tab when I click selector part

It can be very useful for those who need to write and verify complex selectors.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/natu-websync/aohpgnblncapofbobbilnlfliihianac

[image]