# copy results of find(ctrl+f) from chrome inspect

Tags: google-chrome, web-scraping, web-crawler, inspect

I'm very familiar with using selectors, but is there a way to copy the find(ctrl+f) results from the chrome inspection?

For example, if I type "#items img", 25 img tags under #items will be highlighted.

So I was wondering if there is a way to copy the HTML contents of the selected 25 img tags. (of course without having to ctrl+c 25 times!)

I'm aware that I can screen scrape using any programming language and tools such as Selenium, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this from the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `$$('<CSS Selector>')` in your *console* to get the output of your CSS selector.

So, you can run a function in your console to get copy the elements to your clipboard. Somehting like (you can build on this):

```
copy($$('.class').map(e => e).join('\n'))
```

or [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to copy the output in text format:

```
copy($$('.class').map(e => e.textContent).join('\n'))
```

See also:

- [How to get CSS selectors to work in the Developer Tools for Chrome 17?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9212797/12349734)